# How to derive this formula involving the characteristic polynomial of a square matrix of order $3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, symmetric-polynomials

Let $P_A$ denote the characteristic polynomial for a $3\times3$ matrix $A$. Then
$\newcommand{\Tr}{\text{Tr}}$
$$ P_A(x)=\frac{1}{6}[\Tr^3(A)+2\Tr(A^3)-3\Tr(A)\Tr(A^2)]-\frac{1}{2}[\Tr^2(A)-\Tr(A^2)]x+\Tr(A)x^2-x^3.$$
I am wondering if there is a way to derive this without naively calculating each term and comparing whether this equal to the determinant $\det(A-xI).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an application of [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Expressing_elementary_symmetric_polynomials_in_terms_of_power_sums); the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial are elementary symmetric polynomials in the eigenvalues of $A$, and the traces of the powers of $A$ are power sums of the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. Do you know about this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faddeev%E2%80%93LeVerrier_algorithm

Comment: @SuperMario You're welcome, and I did not know about this.

Comment: It turns out that this formula can be explained by this algorithm, however, the proof is somewhat involved for me because I don't know much about Newton's identities.

Comment: It suffices to know that $\Tr(A^k)=\alpha^k+\beta^k+\gamma^k$, and that the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial are
$$\alpha\beta\gamma,\qquad \alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma,\qquad \alpha+\beta+\gamma,$$
where $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are the eigenvalues of $A$. Then without Newton's identities it is not hard to verify your identity, by simply writing them out. Newton's identities do give analogous expressions for characteristic polynomials of square matrices of any size.

Comment: This makes things so much clearer! Thanks a lot...